# How to add headers to Django test requests?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-testing, django-tests

how to use headers with django test requests?

I have requests like this:

```
requests.get(url=MY_URL, headers={"key": MY_KEY})
requests.post(url=MY_URL, json=MY_DATA, headers={"key": MY_KEY})
```

and it's working.

Right now I'm writing tests for some module and I have problem with key varialbe, because I've tried:

```
 self.client.get(MY_URL, **{"key": MY_KEY})
 self.client.get(MY_URL, headers={"key": MY_KEY})
 self.client.post(MY_URL, MY_DATA, **{"key": MY_KEY})
 self.client.post(MY_URL, MY_DATA, headers={"key": MY_KEY})
```

and all this requests return response 400. My guess is that there is something wrong with header. Do you know how to write this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

add the prefix `HTTP_` to whatever objects you wanna pass.
for example, if I want to pass `"dog": "rexy"`
it will be a `client.post("some_req", HTTP_dog="rexy")`

Answer (score 0):

You should debug the prepared request and make sure your headers are in place correctly. I'm pretty sure your syntax is correct.

```py
response = self.client.get(...)
print(response.request.__dict__)
```